# Is it allowed to put a tag anywhere in html other than the common place?

Tags: php, html, css

I've made a sample code as below code to dynamically create pages using php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        echo '<div>' . '<p>' . 'generated by php' . '</div>';
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I decided to use an external css file and refer to it by using the **LINK** tag in the head tag And no styles were applied to the **DIV** generated.
What I did at last was putting the LINK tag anywhere after the PHP code and voila... it worked perfectly. Is there any restrictions about where to put a link tag or not?

Comment: Would that be better to use jquery to apply the styles after the document was completely loaded?

Comment: If you just want to import a CSS file then you would use a `link` element in the `head` of the HTML.  We can't really tell you why your attempt didn't work if you're not showing the actual HTML that didn't work.  If I understand you correctly, you're showing us the code that *does* work and asking us why *some other code* doesn't work?

Comment: The code that was not working is described as clear as I could. I did not wrote it because it contained two parts. Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link tag can actually be placed any where on your file, either in the `<head>` section of your HTML or in the PHP part. This is because the actual formatting using the rules specified in your css file are performed by the browser — the server (and hence PHP) code has nothing to do with how css files are applied. I would check the HTML output generated by your PHP code and the initial output when the `<link>` was in the `<head>` section (assuming it was correctly placed in the `<head>` of the HTML and compare the 2 (from the client browser's perspective, that is!)